# How can I generate thumbnail previews for FLV files on Mac?

Tags: mac, thumbnails, flv

Similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/409533/how-can-i-generate-thumbnail-previews-for-flv-files-in-windows-7) question, however, the answer will not work because it is suited for Windows 7.

My initial thought was to just run the video on VLC and pause the video and then just `Shift`+`Cmd`+`4` and grab the area in order to generate a thumb, but I was wondering if there was a way to get a cleaner, more precise thumbnail for FLV files on Mac. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching around a bit, I found this: https://github.com/Marginal/QLVideo

### QuickLook Video

> This package allows OSX Finder to display thumbnails, static previews,
>   cover art and metadata for most types of video files.
>
> QuickLook and Spotlight on OSX 10.9 and later understand a limited
>   number of media files - mostly only MPEG audio and video codecs within
>   MPEG container files. This package adds support for wide range of
>   other codecs and "non-native" media file types, including `.asf`,
>   `.avi`, `.flv`, `.mkv`, `.rm`, `.webm`, `.wmf` etc.
>
> [image: Example]

It was discussed in this thread here and developed by user Marginal: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26309204#26309204

Comment: Nice find! Thanks. It's a shame the preview in "Get Info" is not allowed to be saved as an image. If you drag and drop, it just copies the file. But the image is there, so I will just shift+cmd+4 that. Cleaner than pausing VLC at a random point in time.

Answer (score -2):

From your follow-up comment above it sounds like you don't (just) want thumbnails in Finder but instead snapshots saved to a separate file?

If so, you can [do this with VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Take_a_snapshot/).